# Create a "release notes" screen in WinForms using Infragistics NetAdvantage components

Tags: winforms, infragistics, netadvantage

I've "inherited" a fairly substantial Winforms project using the Infragistics NetAdvantage 2007 Vol. 2 set of components.

I'm not awfully familiar with those, and how I'm facing a problem - someone who knows them probably will have a solution in no time - so here's my question:

I'm tasked with creating a "Release Notes" screen, which should show the last couple of changes made to the app, with a version number, release dates, and a brief explanation what was changed in that version. Coming from ASP.NET, I thought I'd use a simple enough database table, and a repeater or templatable listview control or something, to show the release notes, something like:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Version 1.0.7                      Released Mar 1, 2010 |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Fixes in this version:                                  |
| * Case-12345: fixed                                     |
| * Case-12346: fixed                                     |
| * Case-12347: fixed                                     |
|                                                         |
| New Features in this version:                           |
| * FEA-2570: implemented................................ |
| * FEA-2571: implemented................................ |
| * FEA-2572: implemented................................ |
+=========================================================+
| Version 1.0.6                     Released Feb 12, 2010 |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Fixes in this version:                                  |
| * Case-11345: fixed                                     |
|                                                         |
| New Features in this version:                           |
| * FEA-1570: implemented................................ |
```

But I can't seem to find any Winforms controls that every remotely or vaguely resemble this......

Any ideas? Any takers? Anything in Winforms itself, or in the Infragistics set of components, that would allow me to create such a screen easily??

Thanks for any hints and pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Infragistics controls but if you are comfortable with HTML you could use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control or if you prefer RTF - [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, those are two good ideas - thanks for the input. I'll ponder those :-)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer directly except to say that NetAdvantage skills are reasonably specialised and you might get more joy asking in the Infragistics forums themselves. I'm more familiar to the ASP.NET side of their controls.